# Use if then logic in NSPredicate for Fetch Request

Tags: swift, core-data

I currently have a list of entities that I am trying to query. It has two properties, id and value. I want to perform a query where it first checks that the ids do not match (`NSPredicate(format: "id != %@", id)`). But I also want to check, if the id does match then if make sure the values don't (`NSPredicate(format: "media.mediaType != %@", mediaType.coredataID as NSNumber)`). So the query is attempting to get all entities that either are not the matching id with any value, or if they are the matching id, then not the matching value.

Using a compound predicate cause this to fetch neither the matching id or value which I don't want. I'm not sure if there is a way to other than filtering out the matching values after just querying the id.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
        
var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []
    
let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id != %@", id)
let valuePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "value != %@", value)
predicates.append(idPredicate)
predicates.append(valuePredicate)

request.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
```

Comment: A suggestion would be to write plain `if`, with `or`/`and`, as you were managing a `Entity` instance, and then write the predicate, with multiple `NSCompoundPredicate`, or write yourself the `OR`/`AND` in the `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code snippet  that uses the correct logic for your query:

```swift
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")

let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id != %@", id)
let valuePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(id == %@) AND (value != %@)", id, value)

let finalPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [idPredicate, valuePredicate])
request.predicate = finalPredicate
```

In this code, the `idPredicate` remains the same to filter out entities with non-matching IDs. The `valuePredicate` is constructed with a compound condition, checking if the ID matches and the value is not the one you're looking for. Finally, the `finalPredicate` combines these two predicates with an OR condition to achieve the desired logic: either the ID doesn't match or, if it does, the value should be different.